# Подключение qss файла к PyQt5 приложению

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss

Подключаю qss файл по инструкции - стили не подключаются. Хотя `print` исправно выводит правильное содержимое `stream.readAll()`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.btn_box = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.exit_button = QPushButton("х")

        self.btn_box.addWidget(self.exit_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    file = QtCore.QFile(r"data/data_pink.qss")
    file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text)
    stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
    app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*data_pink.qss*:

```
QPushButton#exit_button {
font: 12pt "Montserrat Alternates";
background-color: #292f32;
color: #efe2cd;
padding: 5;
border: 1px solid #f4726e;
border-radius: 10px;
}
QPushButton#exit_button:pressed {
font: 11pt "Montserrat Alternates";
background-color: #323335;
color: #efe2cd;
padding: 5;
border: 1px solid #f4726e;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя, указанное после "#" в `qss` - не имя переменной. Его необходимо отдельно указать:
`self.exit_button.setObjectName('exit_button')`